# Asynchronous Webservice

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, weblogic, asynchronous

I wanted to clear something about Asynchronous Webservices.

I read that weblogic give you the ability to create **Asynchronous** Webservices.

but I also read that it's only supported as log as the client and the server of the webservice **both** working under Weblogic container.

Is that true? 
is it possible to create Asynchronous Webservices without having the need to have the **same** system(weblogic, jboss) both at client adn server side?

In case it's possible I would like to get details how is it working..

thanks,
ray.

Comment: Would you mind pointing out where you read the information you cited in "I read that weblogic give you the ability to create Asynchronous Webservices." and "but I also read that it's only supported as log as the client and the server of the webservice both working under Weblogic container."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither WS-Addressing nor Weblogic have anything to do with enabling async services. See the [Asynchronous Client](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.5/docs/asynch.html) documentation for [JAX-WS](http://jax-ws.java.net/). There are two basic approaches supported: Static stubs and the [Dispatch API](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.5/docs/dispatch.html). Static stubs require the use of customizations and will result in additional methods being added to the service endpoint interface. These methods expose both polling and callback functionality for async invocation.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that I can invoke async webservice as long as both the server and the client supports:  WS-Addressing specification.

ray.